# Python - Pandas - Multi-index - Generic code to grab last index and the data

Tags: python, pandas, select, generic-programming, multi-index

Assuming the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
ticker_date = [('US','AAPL',datetime.date.today()-datetime.timedelta(3)),
('US','AAPL',datetime.date.today()-datetime.timedelta(2)),
('US','AAPL',datetime.date.today()-datetime.timedelta(1)),
('US','MSFT',datetime.date.today()-datetime.timedelta(3)),
('US','MSFT',datetime.date.today()-datetime.timedelta(2)),
('US','MSFT',datetime.date.today()-datetime.timedelta(1)),
('EU','TOT',datetime.date.today()-datetime.timedelta(3)),
('EU','TOT',datetime.date.today()-datetime.timedelta(2)),
('EU','TOT',datetime.date.today()-datetime.timedelta(1)),
('EU','CA', datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(3)),
('EU','CA', datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(2)),
('EU','CA', datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(1))
]
index_df = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(ticker_date)
example = pd.DataFrame([12.5,20.5,30.4,10.25,1.0,136,12.2,24.7,37.3,15.1,30.4,45.4],index_df,['value'])
```

I am looking for a line of code to get:

```
df.loc['US'].loc['AAPL']
```

in a generic way - Generic meaning that I will apply some methods on my DataFrames, but these DataFrames can have different Index Levels, depending on the situation. If I add a layer, my code could be:

```
df.loc['EQUITY'].loc['US].loc['AAPL'].
```

The Index Levels are variables. But the objective is always the same, get the dates and the data value.

Comment: `df.unstack().iloc[:, -1]` work for you? I have a feeling it may work for you, but doesn't generalise well.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was not clear enought. I am looking for a generic code that will always grab the last index values (dates) and the data. So for instance, US/AAPL: the dates and the data, US/MSFT, the dates and the data, and so on... However, it is Country and Stock_ticker here, but it could be a multi-index Dataframe with more layers. For instance: EQUITY/US/AAPL/Dates or EQUITY/OPTION/US/AAPL/Dates. Basically, I would like to grab the Data for each specific case. I hope it makes sense

Comment: So, does `df.reset_index(level=-1).groupby(level=[0, 1]).last()` not work?

Comment: Why isn't it generic? What do you even mean by generic?

Comment: To be more specific, I am looking for a line that would get me, for the US/AAPL case: `df.loc['US'].loc['AAPL']` - Generic meaning that my multi-index levels are variable. Meaning I can apply the same calculation on different DataFrames.

Comment: There's nothing generic about _that_. Alright, I don't think I can help you. Good luck.